# How to go from this serialize result to this JSON

Tags: javascript, datatables

This  code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var table = $('#listtable').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
            orderable: false,
            targets: [1,2,3]
        }]
    });

    $('button').click( function() {      
          //var data_sent_to_server = JSON.stringify(table.$('input').serializeArray());
          var data_sent_to_server = JSON.stringify(table.$('input').serializeArray());
          // var data_sent_to_server = JSON.stringify(table.tableToJSON());

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",  
            url: "<?php echo base_url('/material/FromMaterial/');?>",            
            data: data_sent_to_server,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) { 
            console.log("Data sent to the server: \n\n "+data_sent_to_server);
            console.log("Data recieved from the server: \n\n "+data);
            },
            error: function() {
            console.log('Error....');
        }
        });
        //event.preventDefault;
        return false;        
    });
});`
```

Result in this:

```
[{"name":"MaterialId","value":"a0GC0000018TPfdMAG"},{"name":"Opportunity","value":"006C000000bpdl2IAA"},{"name":"TotalOrdered","value":"3"},{"name":"MaterialId","value":"a0GC0000014GyBSMA0"},{"name":"Opportunity","value":"006C000000bpdl2IAA"},{"name":"TotalOrdered","value":"0"},{"name":"MaterialId","value":"a0GC0000006v4ZaMAI"},{"name":"Opportunity","value":"006C000000bpdl2IAA"},{"name":"TotalOrdered","value":"0"},{"name":"MaterialId","value":"a0GC000000nl1UxMAI"},{"name":"Opportunity","value":"006C000000bpdl2IAA"},{"name":"TotalOrdered","value":"1"}]
```

but it should be like this:

```
[ 
   { 
      "MaterialId":"a0GC0000018TPfdMAG",
      "Opportunity":"006C000000bpdl2IAA",
      "TotalOrdered":"3"
   },
   { 
      "MaterialId":"a0GC0000014GyBSMA0",
      "Opportunity":"006C000000bpdl2IAA",
      "TotalOrdered":"0"
   },
   { 
      "MaterialId":"a0GC0000006v4ZaMAI",
      "Opportunity":"006C000000bpdl2IAA",
      "TotalOrdered":"0"
   },
   { 
      "MaterialId":"a0GC000000nl1UxMAI",
      "Opportunity":"006C000000bpdl2IAA",
      "TotalOrdered":"1"
   }
]
```

This is the HTML Table

```
<table id="listtable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" style="width:100%">
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Budgeted</th>
    <th>Total Ordered</th>
 </tr> 
</thead>
        <tr>
    <td>Black Can Liners 43" x 48</td>
    <td>Material</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="MaterialId"  value="a0GC0000018TPfdMAG"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="Opportunity" value="006C000000bpdl2IAA"/>
        <input type="number" name="TotalOrdered" value="0" pattern="[0-9]*"  min="0" max="3">
    </td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Non-Acid Disinfectant - Per Gl</td>
    <td>Material</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="MaterialId"  value="a0GC0000014GyBSMA0"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="Opportunity" value="006C000000bpdl2IAA"/>
        <input type="number" name="TotalOrdered" value="0" pattern="[0-9]*"  min="0" max="2">
    </td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Wet Mop-Blue</td>
    <td>Equipment</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="MaterialId"  value="a0GC0000006v4ZaMAI"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="Opportunity" value="006C000000bpdl2IAA"/>
        <input type="number" name="TotalOrdered" value="0" pattern="[0-9]*"  min="0" max="1">
    </td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Xcelente Multi Purpose Cleaner -Gl</td>
    <td>Material</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="MaterialId"  value="a0GC000000nl1UxMAI"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="Opportunity" value="006C000000bpdl2IAA"/>
        <input type="number" name="TotalOrdered" value="1" pattern="[0-9]*"  min="0" max="1">
    </td>
    </tr>
      </table>
```

How can I get this, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because `serializeArray()`. The serializeArray() method creates an array of objects (name and value) by serializing form values.
Please refer to [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serializearray.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     var data_sent_to_server = [];
     table.rows().data().each(function(d){
        var obj = {}
        $(d[3]).each(function(i, e){
            if($(e).is("input")){
                obj[$(e).attr("name")] = $(e).val()
            }
        });
        data_sent_to_server.push(obj)
     });
     console.log(data_sent_to_server)
```

There's probably a much more elegant way of doing it but this works. Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/wsch891n/

**NOTE**

As has been pointed out using the method above only gets the original values, to get current values from the input you can use jQuery:

```
     var data_sent_to_server = [];
     table.$('tr').each(function(i, row){
        var obj = {}
        $(row).find('input').each(function(e, input){
            obj[$(input).attr("name")] = $(input).val()
        })
        data_sent_to_server.push(obj)
     });
     console.log(data_sent_to_server);
```

This gets the correct values but I'm almost sure that there would be a way of updating the underlying data on change of the input - that'd be a good exercise to try, then you wouldn't need to worry about paging etc... I've updated the JSFiddle.

Comment: nice solution.
observation: The field TotalOrdered is an Input how to get the value the user input in it, in the working example always has the value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do any of the JSON stuff. Just call serializeArray() on your form/inputs, pass the result with your ajax, then see what arrives in your POST. That being said, below is my way of converting your data.

Wrap the inputs inside a form and give the form an id. Change your button click event listener to prevent submission of the form

```
$('button').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

The function below will return an object in the way you describe.

```
function jsonFormData (formId) {
    const arr = $('#' + formId).serializeArray(), obj = {};
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(obj[arr[i].name] === undefined) {
            obj[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
        } else {
            if(!(obj[arr[i].name] instanceof Array)) {
                obj[arr[i].name] = [obj[arr[i].name]];
            }
            obj[arr[i].name].push(arr[i].value);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```